# Concrete example of using the "memory" clobber to form a read/write memory barrier

Tags: assembly, gcc, x86, inline-assembly, memory-barriers

Below is excerpted from the [GCC manual's Extended Asm docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Extended-Asm), on the "memory" clobber when embedding assembly instructions in C using `asm` keyword:

> The "memory" clobber tells the compiler that the assembly code
> performs memory reads or writes to items other than those listed in
> the input and output operands (for example, accessing the memory
> pointed to by one of the input parameters). To ensure memory contains
> correct values, GCC may need to flush specific register values to
> memory before executing the asm. Further, the compiler does not assume
> that any values read from memory before an asm remain unchanged after
> that asm; it reloads them as needed. *Using the "memory" clobber
> effectively forms a read/write memory barrier for the compiler*.

The italic sentence implies a possible programming practice in which the "memory" clobber serves as a memory barrier. The read/write memory barrier is a requirement that memory-reads (loads) and memory-writes (stores) issue in the order specified in the program code. So, my understanding of the sentence is that we can assure that the memory reads/writes codes before the `asm` statement be executed strictly before the memory reads/writes codes after the `asm` statement, if we use the "memory" clobber in the `asm` statement in between properly. To understand how this is accomplished, I tried to construct a concrete example of `asm` statement that demonstrates the capability of "memory" clobber being a memory barrier. But I failed to do it. I had thought the two sentences before (one about flushing, another about assumption of unchangedness) can help suggest such an example, but I cannot see any relation between them.

As a result, I ask here for a concrete example that illustrates the italic sentence: an `asm` statement using  "memory" clobber, together with surrounding non-asm memory reads/writes codes, which can demonstrates how the "memory" clobber forms a read/write memory barrier.

The only assembly language I am familiar with is Intel x86 assembly, so please make the example targeted on that platform. If it is not possible, MIPS assembly is also ok of which I'm almost oblivious. Thank you.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're looking for, but is it something like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/hY41qc9T9)?  In `foo1` there is only one load from `x`, in `foo2` there are two.

Comment: https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/ has some examples and goes into detail about the whole concept.   Note that pure *compiler* barriers like `asm("" ::: "memory")` basically give you the memory ordering strength of the underlying asm memory model (but see [Who's afraid of a big bad optimizing compiler?](//lwn.net/Articles/793253/) on LWN for more caveats). So some ISAs will still need an actual barrier instruction (MIPS, PowerPC) where others won't (x86).  That's why normally you'd want to use `atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_release)` or whatever in portable code.

Comment: https://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/ re: underlying asm memory models.

Comment: @Nate Eldredge: I think this is a good example for the sentence before the italic one: (if "memory" clobber is specified), "the compiler does not assume that any values read from memory before an `asm` remain unchanged after that `asm`; it reloads them as needed."

Comment: And is that not what you were looking for?  I think the italicized sentence is just a summary of the paragraph, so that the preceding sentences are a definition of what they mean by "barrier".

Comment: @Peter Cordes: It took me a few days to read the articles in that series. Yes, `asm("" ::: "memory")` is an example preventing compiler reordering. But, 1) that series of articles seemed to relate the term "memory barrier" to processor reordering or memory reordering, but in the GCC online doc, this term is used to refer to the technique that prevents compiler reordering; the processor reordering is called "speculative read" in the GCC doc (see the paragraph that immediately follows). Due to this term difference, ...

Comment: Right, `asm("" ::: "memory")` is a *compiler* barrier.  https://preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time/.  That's sometimes not all you need, so there's also a need to discuss barriers that involve an asm instruction to give extra runtime ordering, as well as blocking compile-time reordering.  Usually people just say "memory barrier" when talking about a runtime barrier, but that term could also be applied to a barrier that only blocks compile-time reordering.

Comment: Especially when the underlying machine's memory model is strong, like x86, so `atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release)`, or anything other than seq_cst, can be implemented correctly by `asm("" ::: "memory")`.

Comment: ... I think the explanation of "read/write memory barrier" I wrote in the question does not reflect what I want. That explanation is for #LoadStore# memory barrier (which is different from compiler barrier), if using the notation of articles in preshing. But the GCC doc only says the "memory" clobber can work as a compiler barrier that prevents assembly code from reordering (can be detected using disasembly); it does not say the "memory" clobber can further prevent memory reordering. ...

Comment: ... I did not know the difference when I submit the question so people may think I want an example of memory barrier. Now I know I should have asked for an example of compiler barrier. I apologize for the confusion. 2) Although preshing.com/20120625/memory-ordering-at-compile-time talked a lot about compiler barriers, it still does not explain why `asm volatile("" ::: "memory");` can work as an (explicit) compiler barrier. I could not answer myself after reading and thinking for many days. This sounds like a new question, but I would greatly appreciate it if someone can please tell me. ...

Comment: ... 3) This is a side note. If "read/write memory barrier" in GCC online doc means a #LoadStore" memory barrier, x86 has implemented it automatically because a load instruction of x86 conforms to acquire semantics while a store instruction of x86 conforms to release semantics. So, on x86, "read/write memory barrier" is achieved by combination of the two. Am I right? If so, on x86, we can "effectively forms a read/write memory barrier" without using the "memory" clobber, right? Thank you.